# TextStyle and no effect of coloring the text

Tags: wix, wix3.5

I have defined the TextStyle as

```
<TextStyle Id="subHeadingFont" FaceName="Tahoma" Size="9" Bold="yes" Blue="255" Italic="yes" Green="0" Red="0" />
```

and Later used it in control like this

```
<Control Id="Password" Type="Edit" X="20" Y="195" Width="150" Height="18" Property="WIXUI_SA.PASSWORD" Indirect="yes" Text="{\subHeadingFont}" ToolTip="Password Dude"/>
```

On the UI I don't get the text in Blue, any pointers what did I do wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems its not possible to change the color of "edit" control
Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372074(v=vs.85).aspx

> This column specifies the text color displayed by a Text Control. All other types of controls always use the default text color.